# How to achieve launch service or topic in ROS2 TEST?

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm writing TEST for the company ROS2's project.I learned to launch service or topic via the .test file in ROS,but there is no .test file in ROS2 TEST.I don't know what kind of mechanism can launch service or topic in ROS2
TEST.

Additional information:I use

```
ament test --only-packages MY_PACKAGE_NAME
```

to run TEST.
Thanks All

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292100/how-to-achieve-launch-service-or-topic-in-ros2-test-?/) by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-05-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The functionality you are referring to is provided by `rostest` in ROS 1.

There is currently no equivalent of rostest in ROS 2. Now that there is a new launch system in Bouncy, we should be closer to being able to add such functionality in ROS 2.

Currently the only ROS 2 tests running multiple processes are pytests using `launch`. Some examples can be found on the [demos repository](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/3593af7f4cee6446cf263b890f1fd3ff839ceea1/demo_nodes_cpp/test/test_executables_tutorial.py.in).

HTH,

EDIT:

> I tried to launch processes in background in the ros2 test,but this way can't meet the expected requirements.

@RachelRen Can you clarify which ones are the requirements of your setup that are not met ?
As a `rostest` port will "do the same thing" aka launching other nodes in different processes, I would expect the behavior to be similar as launching them with `launch`.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-07-06**:
@marguedas Thank you very much.

I tried to launch processes in background in the ros2 test,but this way can't meet the expected requirements.I'm looking forward to this functionality to be added in ROS2 .

Thank you

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-08-06**:
@marguedas I'm sorry to comment too late.

I mean,when launching processes in background,the publisher don't publish data to the topic.It's really the phenomenon I have encountered.

Such as,
after launch `realsense_ros2_camera &`,the subscriber can't call the callback.
`realsense_ros2_camera` is OK

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-08-07**:
Can you provide a reproducible example involving only packages available in a standard ROS 2 installation?

I just tried:
`./install_debug_isolated/demo_nodes_cpp/lib/demo_nodes_cpp/talker &`
and `ros2 topic echo /chatter` and couldn't reproduce the issue

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-11-30**:
Hi ,

I have little different question on the same topic.
I migrated .test file from ros1 into launch.py file in ros2 and able to test using

```
ros2 launch pkg-name filename.launch.py
```

But i want to do the same from CMakelist.txt with gtest, is it possible to do this? any help?
Thanks.

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-12-03**:
@poonam1120

Would you mind to introduce how you achieved the migrated .test file from ros1 into launch.py in ros2?

Thank you!

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-12-03**:
@poonam1120

Have you tried adding .py to CMakeLists.txt using `ament_add_pytest_test`?

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2018-12-04**:
@RachelRen, i have not tried using "ament_add_pytest_test" .. will give a try.

About migrating .test file into launch.py, I have referred the "test_launch_ros" from launch package ( master branch of ros2) .

thanks.

**Comment by [hect1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/38874/hect1995/) on 2019-07-29**:
I cannot find the source you are providing to look for the migration. Can you share the link? I am trying to put a test node into my normal launch file (with normal nodes) and I do not know how to do it in ROS2